# i have problem in ajax Post not display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have table with search fields seprated to
1- table header contain "search fields - table headers"
2- table body => come from ajax post method
3- pagination => come from ajax post method after data excuted "i used setTimeout to delay this function"

[image: table data without filter]

the data display automaticly in the table body by ajax post & if the user use search fields also the data filterd by search words and pagingation also display basd on data

[image: table data with filter]

i have 2 cases
1- in the main page the table loaded with the page and evry thing working fine i used the follwing function:
follwing function responsible for data

```
    jsQueryDataLive(defaultPageNo);
  function jsQueryDataLive(defaultPageNo){
  var objData = {
    action     : dataTableName +'/QueryData',
    ajaxClass  : actionSplit0,
    ajaxPage   : defaultPageNo,
  };
  $('#form-query-main').find(":input").each(function(){
    objData[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });
  // console.log(objData);
  // NOTE: the below line is Responsible for determining the location we need to view data on
  var locationID = '#main-table-tbody';
  ajaxPost(objData, locationID);
}
```

the following function for pagination

```
    jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);
  function jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo){
  setTimeout(function () {
    var objData = {
      action     : dataTableName +'/Pagination',
      ajaxClass  : actionSplit0,
      ajaxPage   : defaultPageNo,
    };
    // document.getElementById("jsData").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(objData);

    // NOTE: the below line is Responsible for determining the location we need to view data on
    var locationID = '#pagination';
    ajaxPost(objData, locationID);

  }, 100);
}
```

i used the following function for filter

```
   $('.searchField').keyup(function() {
   jsPageNo(defaultPageNo);

  } );


 function jsPageNo(defaultPageNo) {
 jsQueryDataLive(defaultPageNo);
 jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);
```

}

2- the second case is when i want to display the obove bage in the modal

[image]

as you see in the page the table and data display correctly
i used this function to define table and load the main bag :

```
    var dataTableName;
jsDataTableName();
function jsDataTableName(tableName) {

  if (tableName === undefined) {
    dataTableName = actionSplit0;
    // console.log(dataTableName);

  }
  else {
    dataTableName = tableName;
    console.log(dataTableName);

    // NOTE: load External Class Query page
    jsLoadExternalClass();

  }
}

    function jsLoadExternalClass(){
  var objData = {
    action     : dataTableName +'/Query',
    ajaxClass  : actionSplit0,
    ajaxPage   : defaultPageNo,
  };

  // document.getElementById("jsData").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(objData);
  // jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);

  // NOTE: the below line is Responsible for determining the location we need to view data on
  var locationID = '#externalClass1';
  ajaxPost(objData, locationID);
  jsPageNo(defaultPageNo);
}
```

the problem with me in filtered not working when i type imediatly but it work after i close the modal and re open it again 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e578p.jpg)
[image]

also if there is a better solution to start function jsPaginationLive after jsQueryDataLive finished instead of setTimeout please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you set the timer on setTimeout from 100 ms to 2,000, does it still have the issue? One of the problems I've run into when using timeouts to handle situations like these is that any variance in the loading times of the site (which can always vary for any number of reasons) can cause your timeout to fail to achieve your goal.

So instead I'd suggest this: either add a variable which is set by the data function upon completion or you could use a value in the data function which must not be undefined before proceeding, then have the pagination function in a setInterval, like this:

```
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
 if (dataHasLoaded){ // This will be whatever the you decide to name the variable
   jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);
   clearInterval(interval);
  }
},500);
```

This will ensure that the pagination function will never attempt to load before the data has been fully loaded.

EDIT: Alternatively, you can place "jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);" somewhere at the end of "jsQueryDataLive(defaultPageNo);" so it won't attempt pagination until the data function has completed.

Answer to 2nd question:

If you want to only run an interval while a user is typing, you can do something like this:

```
  var interval;
  window.onkeydown = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      if (dataHasLoaded){
         jsPaginationLive(defaultPageNo);
         clearInterval(interval);
        }
     },500);
  }

    var keyTimeout;
    window.onkeyup = function(){
    clearTimeout(keyTimeout);
        keyTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
           clearInterval(interval);
        }, 5000); // The interval will be cleared 5 seconds after the last keypress. Change as needed.
    }
```

I feel like there's a cleaner way to do this, though. Why do you want the interval  to only be active during typing?

Comment: thank you very much. Your solution solved my both problems @JLowther

Comment: but i have another broblem now is : i want to start setInterval when the user start typing and when he finished typing should be stop.

Comment: @tokhy2000 I added the 2nd answer above.

Comment: when i using search by "keyup" through time of clearInterval it's working but after finished the time not working agin. how can i start setInterval with keyup

Comment: Oh, sorry: you'll need to start the interval on keydown as well. I would wrap the interval in "window.onkeydown = function(){ ... }" and change the other event listener to be "window.onkeyup".

Comment: @tokhy2000 I edited the answer to include the interval handling as well.

Comment: i trying new sultion frist load and stop working fine, after onkeydown the funciton working fine too. but setInterval not stoped "onkeyup not working i don't know why?" Please help me

Comment: @tokhy2000 Sorry, it needed one more "clearInterval(interval)" in the first function. I've added it in the answer above.

Comment: i'm so sorry @JLowther for bothering you. the search function started and stopped fine with search now if i'm in the pop up but if i open any app in my laptop "using Alt + tab" or closed the pop up and go to the main page form and type any thing the function re active and not stopped. can i define if i type in spsific input like $('.searchField').keyup(function()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206389/discussion-between-jlowther-and-tokhy2000).